# Prioritise conditional formatting rule

Tags: excel, vba

How can I prioritise this conditional formatting rule so that it takes precedence over any other rules?

```
If Not Intersect(Target, oTbl_1.DataBodyRange) Is Nothing Then
    oTbl_2.DataBodyRange.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
    oTbl_1.DataBodyRange.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
    sFind = oTbl_1.ListColumns(1).Range(Target.Row).Value
    Set rCL = oTbl_2.ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange.Find(sFind)
    If Not rCL Is Nothing Then Cells(rCL.Row, Target.Column).Interior.Color = RGB(184, 204, 228)
End If
```

Comment: That's not a conditional formatting rule.  (Conditional formatting uses the `.FormatConditions` property of the range object.)  That is just straight VBA formatting of cells.  Are your other "rules" actually conditional formatting rules, or are they just VBA code too?

Comment: The others are traditional rules.

Comment: Conditional formatting takes precedence over cell formatting, and your VBA is just setting cell formatting.  So you either (a) have to manually apply this rule using conditional formatting, or (b) change your VBA to set the conditional formatting for this rule, or (c) change your conditional formatting rules to be applied via VBA instead (and, within VBA, apply the rules in whichever order you want).

Comment: How can I convert it using option (b)?

Comment: I'm afraid I have no idea - I tend to avoid conditional formatting within Excel (and just use VBA) so I have absolutely no experience of using VBA to set conditional formatting.